# Problems with getting data via ajax from mysql db

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cordova

Im opening a inappbrowser window for a payment service. After the Payment is done and sucessfull entries in my db will be updated.

user table - rows like

```
ID - USERNAME - VIPSTATUS - CALLSTATUS
```

The vipstatus and callstatus gets changed to "1" after payment.When the inappbrowser will be closed i want to get the new data from the vipstatus and callstatus from the user and overwrite the existing localstorage items callstatus and vip status. Username is saved in localstorage as username.
Im guessing my ajaxcode is wrong, because it dont work, it dont even load the script.

**My Ajax Code**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
                  $("#paybutton").click(function() {
                                        var params = "projectpaymentoption=1195&id=",
                                        usernamepay = window.localStorage.getItem("username"),
                                        paymenturl = params + usernamepay;

                                        $.ajax({
                                               type: 'POST',
                                               url: 'http://www..de/phone/encode.php',
                                               data: $.param({"paymenturl": paymenturl}),
                                               success: function(result) {
                                               var paybrowser = window.open(result,'_blank','location=no','closebuttoncaption=Zurück');

                                               paybrowser.addEventListener('exit',function(event) {


                                               $.ajax({
                                               type: 'POST',
                                               url: 'http://www..de/update.php',
                                               data: $.param({"username": username}),
                                               success: function(data) {
                                               window.localStorage.setItem("vipstatus", data[2]);
                                               window.localStorage.setItem("callstatus",data[3]);
                                      }
                         });
                  }
```

**My UPDATE.PHP Code**

```
<?php 


  $dbhost = "blabla";
  $dbuser = "blabla";
  $dbpass = "blabla";
  $dbname = "blabla";
  $tableName = "user";


  print_r($_POST);
  $user = $_POST['data']['username'];
  print PHP_EOL . $user . PHP_EOL;

  $con = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
  $dbs = mysqli_select_db($dbname, $con);
  $result = mysqli_query("SELECT user$ FROM $tableName");         
  $array = mysqli_fetch_row($result);           
  $conn->close();
  ?>
```

Comment: Why don't you tag your posting with JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

  $dbhost = "blabla";
  $dbuser = "blabla";
  $dbpass = "blabla";
  $dbname = "blabla";
  $tableName = "user";

  $con = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
  $dbs = mysqli_select_db($con, $dbname);

  print_r($_POST);
  $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['data']['username']);
  print PHP_EOL . $user . PHP_EOL;

  $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT $user FROM $tableName");         
  while ($array = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
  echo $array['vipstatus'];

  echo $array['callstatus'];
  }           
  $conn->close();
  ?>
```

Fixed your mysqli_* query. On `$result` and `$dbs`.

Comment: Just tidied up the code and sanitized the username, I don't like variables that are not prepared/sanitized.

Comment: Technically, that's just a sanitized variable and may not be enough to prevent SQL injection. It would be better to use parameterized queries

Comment: When i use that the the variables in local storage for vipstatus will be "a" and for vipstatus "r". @JamieSterling

Comment: @mav It will input anything you want it to input into vipstatus.

Comment: yeah but i want to get the callstatus and vipstatus from the row for the user and not "a" and "r" :P

Comment: @mav so you want it to update the row callstatus to 1 where username=$user ? from what your update.php is looking like looks as if you want to select rows not UPDATE them.

Comment: I want to read from the table "user" the rows "callstatus" and "vipstatus" for "$user". And then save them in my cordova app as localstorage variable. For each of them 2 @JamieSterling

Answer (score 1):

Your Javascript code is not valid Javascript. It misses some closing brackets. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#paybutton").click(function() {
        var params = "projectpaymentoption=1195&id=",
            usernamepay = window.localStorage.getItem("username"),
            paymenturl = params + usernamepay;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://www..de/phone/encode.php',
            data: $.param({
                "paymenturl": paymenturl
            }),
            success: function(result) {
                var paybrowser = window.open(result, '_blank', 'location=no', 'closebuttoncaption=Zurück');

                paybrowser.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'http://www..de/update.php',
                        data: $.param({
                            "username": username
                        }),
                        success: function(data) {
                            window.localStorage.setItem("vipstatus", data[2]);
                            window.localStorage.setItem("callstatus", data[3]);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```